# Displaying a vector of structs in a html.tera page with rocket web framework

Tags: rust, rocket, tera

Hello i can't figure out how to display a vector of struct.

template rendering:

```
let a: Vec<ResultsStruct> = serde_json::from_value(query_result).unwrap();   
Template::render("index", json!({ "user": user, "c_api": c_api, "query_result": a }))
```

template code:

```
<div class="container">
    {% for i in query_result %}
        {{ i }}
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
```

i would like to print a struct from the vec like this but i can't figure out how.
thank you for the help

i tried to do what it's in the template code up here but nothing works

Comment: You'll have to provide at least some info to go by: What do you want the final result to look like? What does the current code produce? If there are any errors, what are the exact error messages?
"More/detailed information" == "higher chance we can help you".

Comment: there's no need of more information, a is Vec<ResultsStruct> and i simply want to display it in the html tera template

Comment: What is `ResultsStruct`? And what should it look like in the rendered HTML?

Comment: is a vector with structs inside it. and on html.tera i want to display like {{ ResultsStruct.camp1 }} for every struct that's inside the vec